# Did Finn turn off his targeting computer?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I saw The Force Awakens in its first week of release, before most of my friends.  I made a mental note to discuss with them, but forgot it until now.  I can't find anything on the Web mentioning it.

Before Finn (Boyega)  {or maybe it was Poe (Isaac)} fired in the ship he was piloting, he turned off the targeting computer (a la Luke in A New Hope).  The moment was very transitory - not a lot of focus on the movement.

First, can anyone else confirm what I think I saw (5 months ago)?

And if this is true, why would the action be done by him (is it taught in flight school now?), because the action was very reflexive.

Comment: Are you talking about the scene where they escape to Jakku?

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember the details of the scene.  It was one of those two guys, and he was piloting at the time (it wasn't the turret scene on the Falcon).  It was very similar to Luke's scene because he was getting ready for an important shot, or battle.

Comment: Is the question whether or not he switched off his computer, or is it canon that he did and you're asking why?  Just want to make the question is clear.

Comment: I clarified the OP

Answer (score 1):

No, neither scene, escaping the star destroyer, on Jaaku, the assault at the bar, or on the not-the-death-star Star Killer Base involved turning off the targeting computer, by Poe or Finn.

As a thematic almost scene by scene copy, the corresponding scene to Luke's "use the force" moment was Rey's "you will unlock these restraints" moment.

Your remembrance of this in The Force Awakens is like everyone who remembers Luke trying and failing to use his grappling hook in the Death Star during A New Hope. It never happened that way. It's a figment of the imagination.

Comment: Ok.  I'll take your word for it.  Did you see it recently?

Comment: @jason I've seen it multiple times most recently 2 weeks ago.

Comment: I read the end of your answer.  First, I found the scene.  It was the Star Destroyer escape sequence.  Boyega switches the display from his joystick to the HUD.  So, not entirely as I remembered it.  We call that a memory.  Remembrance is what happens on Monday.